Ввод русских символов через консоль yii2
Возникла внезапная проблема - при попытке ввода в консоль русских символов yii2 честно запихивает их в строку нужного размера, однако на экран выводит пустое место. При попытке эти строки передать для сохранения в БД - ловлю ошибку, т.к. БД их также видит пустыми
Код консольного контроллера
class UserController extends Controller
{
    private UserRepository $userRepository;

    public function __construct(
        $id,
        $module,
        UserRepository $userRepository,
        $config = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($id, $module, $config);
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $splitFio = [];

        while (count($splitFio) < 2) {
            $fio = $this->prompt('Введите ФИО пользователя через пробел: ');
            $splitFio = explode(' ', $fio);
        }

        $login = $this->prompt('Введите логин пользователя: ');
        $email = $this->prompt('Введите email пользователя: ');
        $password = $this->prompt('Введите пароль пользователя: ');

        $password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);

        $this->userRepository->save(UserWork::fill(
            $splitFio[0],
            $splitFio[1],
            $login,
            $password,
            $email,
            $splitFio[2] ?? null,
        ));
    }
}

Результат ввода

Попытки конвертировать строку в Unicode или куда-то еще через mb_converting - успехом не увенчались.
